# Thrown Exception not caught in UnitTest try/catch

Tags: c#, oop, exception

I'm designing some code right now where I'm throwing an exception if a string parameter is null or empty and the exception is thrown as it should be, but it isn't getting caught when I'm UnitTesting.

Here's the client I'm using.

```
public class PipeClient : IPipeClient
{
    public async void Send(string host, string pipeName, Message msg)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.PreparedMessage))
            throw new ArgumentException("MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pipeName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (!host.TryParseHost()) 
            throw new ArgumentException("INVALID_HOST_NAME");

        using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(host, pipeName, PipeDirection.Out))
        {
            pipeClient.Connect(200);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
            {
                await Task.Run(() => writer.WriteLine(msg.PreparedMessage));
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the UnitTest

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Send_FailsOnWrongHostName()
    {
        var name = "FailWithHostname";
        var msg = new Message(MyStates.Register, "UnitTest", "Test");

        try
        {
            var client = new PipeClient();
            client.Send("lol", name, msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(e is ArgumentException);
        }
    }
```

So when I run that test it should as far as I know throw the exception when I call the the Send method (which is does) and then get caught in the catch clause because I'm not catching it inside the PipeClient. Yet it doesn't, it just exits with a failed test.

If you need any more information just let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to catch and test the exception. If you are expecting an exception to occur then add`[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException)` notation above your `[TestMethod]`.

Comment: I've tried that previously without success which is why I tried this method instead. 
I get the error that it hasn't thrown an exception, which I don't understand.

Comment: I have of course confirmed with debugging that the method is actually throwing the expected exception.

Comment: It's almost as if it is getting caught by something else.

Comment: Are you sure the exception thrown is actually an ArgumentException? When looking at your code and assuming that indeed an exception occurs, the only thing i could imagine is some method invocation in your Send method throwing some exception of a type different from ArgumentException.

Comment: Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @elgonzo Sorry I should have been more clear previously. I confirmed that the exception was thrown and it was an ArgumentException.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you, I will be reading up on that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a few things I want to raise in this answer. I'm not sure of your experience level so please don't think I'm being condescending at any point.

Firstly a brief note on async methods and Tasks.

- Async void should be avoided unless in an async event handler. Async methods should return Task or Task otherwise there is nothing for the calling method to keep hold of to know when the method is done and to report back whether the method threw an exception. Async void is essentially fire and forget, there is no one left to observe the exceptions.

> "In observed Tasks no one can you scream" -Me ,2018

- Exceptions thrown in async methods are nicely unwrapped and thrown
  when the async method is awaited, with the call stack all preserved
  and reasonably sensible. If you don't await the result eventually at
  some point in the future you will get an UnobservedTaskException
  that, if you haven't configured a global handler for, will bring down
  your application. If you get the result of an async method
  synchronously using .Wait() or .Result or via
  .GetAwaiter().GetResult() (all 3 you should try and avoid but the 3rd
  option is best if you have to I have been informed), then you will
  get the original exception wrapped in an AggregateException.

Now if none of this is making much sense to you, I would recommend doing some reading up Tasks and async/await.

Now onto your Test.

Your method is async void so there is nothing for the calling method to have returned to it to represent the work or to let it know that the method has thrown an exception. So it carries on, the test finishes and then everything completes with no exceptions because the UnobservedTaskException can be thrown at anypoint in the future (I think it is related to when the garbage collector tidies up the faulted Task and then it throws and because the garbage collector is non-deterministic we can't say when that will happen)

So what if you made your async method return a Task??? Well that's still not quite right. You are now returning a Task that will be in a faulted state because of the exception, however because you never await it, the exception is never 'unwrapped' and actually thrown and so you're test happily continues.

What you need to do is make your Test async and return a Task and make the method you're testing async Task not async void and await that method in your test.

Like this

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Send_FailsOnWrongHostName()
{
    var name = "FailWithHostname";
    var msg = new Message(MyStates.Register, "UnitTest", "Test");

    try
    {
        var client = new PipeClient();
        await client.Send("lol", name, msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(e is ArgumentException);
    }
}

public class PipeClient : IPipeClient
{
    public async Task Send(string host, string pipeName, Message msg)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.PreparedMessage))
            throw new ArgumentException("MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(host) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pipeName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (!host.TryParseHost()) 
            throw new ArgumentException("INVALID_HOST_NAME");

        using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(host, pipeName, PipeDirection.Out))
        {
            pipeClient.Connect(200);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
            {
                await Task.Run(() => writer.WriteLine(msg.PreparedMessage));
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the thorough explanation! I had completely forgotten I made the method asynchronous and missed it when reviewing and refactoring. That’s problem with revisiting code made months ago with no comments or explanations. I wasn’t actually aware that an async void method wouldn’t throw the exception back to a caller but it makes sense. I will test it out tomorrow when I get home and will update with the result. Thank you again!